# Categorical variables and distribution

Tags: r, categorical-data

Let's say a data set has 20 people and each one has a score. People can be classified by their country, region, and race. I want to measure how much each category can describe the distribution of score. For instance, the country category is 100% accurate, while other categories are not. How do I calculate the percentage for other categories? What kind of problem do I have in terms of statistics? Any reference or comments would be much appreciated. [image]
I have added real data here. [image]What I ultimately want to do is to know whether I can accept or reject an alternative hypothesis, the category (speaker's name or scene division) does explain(or accurately predict) the fluctuating scores.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "accurate" and "percentage."  As far as I can tell just by scanning the data, the country completely determines the score in this table, which means one can construct a *perfectly accurate* predictor of the score.

Comment: I am pretty new to statistics. What I was trying to say is how I can compare the second and third categories in order to know which one is more "accurate predictor" of people's scores. I know the second is more accurate and the first one is perfect, but how I can get any numeric value to compare these categorical variables.

Comment: The example above is a quite simplified version of my real data. What I am really trying to do has more than 3000 lines of text. Each line has a score ranging from 0.0 to 1. The scores of lines fluctuate from the first line to the last line. I have several factors/categorical variables that can explain this fluctuation. For instance, I can assign a speaker's name to each line. (The text is a play) Or I can divide the text by scenes. I might have different ways to divide the text. I want to know which factor (speaker, scene division, etc) best explains the fluctuation of scores.

Comment: If this one is a classification problem look at `caret::varImp` or `randomForest::importance` [Look here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153663/how-to-get-the-most-important-variables-in-random-forests-in-r)

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! It looks applicable to my data. I am studying it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you build your prediction model. For example, suppose you have a model that says: for region A the score is 1 and for all other regions the score is zero. Then your model will correctly predict the score for the first two people and incorrectly for the others. Or you can have a model that predicts for region A a score of 0.95, for region B a score of 0.75, etc (I am looking at the midpoint in the distribution of scores by region). There are several metrics that you can use to determine how well your predictions fit the actual data. For example, you can use [mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) (MSE)
$$MSE = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\hat{Y_i})^2,$$
Where error $(Y_i-\hat{Y_i})$ is the difference between the actual $(Y_i)$ value and your prediction $(\hat{Y_i})$. Since you might overpredict or underpredict the true scores, the errors could be either negative (the true value is lower than your prediction, for example, the true score is 0.8 while you predicted 0.9) or positive (the true value is higher than your prediction). The errors are squared because ultimately with MSE we do not care about the direction of the error (overpredict or underpredict), but whether it is close to the true value or not. As a final step you simply average over these squared errors.

MSE and other metrics (for instance, [$R^2$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) can be automatically calculated by statistical software/package of your choice. You can also create your own metrics, it really depends on your research question and the nature of your data.

Regarding your final question about hypothesis testing: you can do a linear regression with your data (where Y is the score and Xs are all your explanatory variables, such as region) and look at the [p-values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) of the explanatory variables.

Comment: I am deeply grateful to you for your very informative guidance!

Comment: I was wondering if you could be more specific about "Xs being all my explanatory variables, such as region." Should I create something like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tirbfjmoxfadzb9/Screen%20Shot%202020-01-12%20at%208.40.49%20PM.png?dl=0 . And I assume I need to get the p-value of the variable of category region.

Comment: For a nice chart to show your results, you can do it without regressions. A boxplot would be great: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot. In a boxplot for each region you show the distribution of scores, and then you can visually compare one region to another. Or you can simply plot one bar per region showing the mean, and then add error bars showing the maximum and minimum scores. Here is an example how to add error bars in Excel: https://www.pryor.com/blog/add-error-bars-and-standard-deviations-to-excel-graphs/